# UWP/XAML broken SvgImageSource scaling

Tags: xaml, svg, uwp, win-universal-app

[Windows 10 1703 introduced `SvgImageSource`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.media.imaging.svgimagesource), which lets you specify an SVG file as the target of the `Source` parameter for an `Image` element.

I'm unable to get scaling to work correctly with SVG images. The result is always padded instead of correctly filling the available space.

I exported the SVG file I have to a PNG as-is (no transformations), and rendered the XAML with the same code:

```
    <Image Stretch="UniformToFill" Source="Assets/MainPage/archway.svg" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" Grid.RowSpan="5" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
```

except once with an svg and once with a png.

The PNG correctly expands to fill the available space:

[image]

but the SVG renders like this:

[image]

I've tried with all the parameters, but to no avail.

Any suggestions?

EDIT

This is the SVG in question: https://pastebin.ca/3840758

Comment: Have you tried removing both alignment settings?

Comment: Yup. That changes nothing in terms of solving the problem.

Comment: Can you post the svg file?

Comment: @Jessica link added in the post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add `preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin"` to your `<svg ...>` tag.

Comment: Note this NOT a uwp Image control issue. Open it up in chrome n you will see the same behavior. So you need to fix your svg by doing this.

Comment: Thank you! I wonder if there is some way to override this behaviour from outside the SVG.